# RSSI to distance moving average

Tags: electromagnetism, signal-processing

I'm calculating distance from an RSSI, and as it seems to have quite a high variation I want to take an exponential moving average.

My question is: Where in this calculation is it most applicable to apply the moving average filter?

Do I want to take the moving average of:

- the RSSI in dBm,
- the power in pW,
- the distance in m, or
- something else?

Comment: Are you interested in just the distance estimate or are you interested in the distance estimate and the quality of said estimate?

Comment: @MathEE I'm interested in both. Which also raises the question: from what do I calculate the quality of the estimate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just "RSSI" is usually a logarithmic signal.  As such, it is not appropriate for averaging.  I think the most appropriate space for averaging is linear fields strength, proportional to volts/meter.  That would be some constant to the power of RSSI.

So for each RSSI reading, do K<sup>RSSI</sup>, low pass filter those, then invert the low pass filtered value to get a rough idea of distance.  Keep in mind that a lot of things effect signal strength than just distance.  These include orientation of both the transmitting and receiving antennas, multi-path destructive or constructive interference, and absorption and blocking of things in the environment.  You will get only a rough idea of distance at best.  If you get within a factor of 2, then consider yourself lucky.

Comment: Thanks @OlinLathrop. Just to confirm, the linear field strength is proportional to the inverse of the distance, correct? Which makes it proportional to `pow(10, (rssi/10-3)/2)`, I think?

Comment: @Alec: Field strength (like volts/meter) in open space is proportional to 1/distance, and power (like watts per square meter) is proportional to 1/(distance squared).

Comment: @Alec There is a bit of a cheat you can do with power when just talking about proportionality.  RSSI ~ log(1/d^2) = -2log(d) ~ -log(d) so you don't have to worry about the square.

Answer (score 0):

You take an average of RSSI.

Reason: -

Distance is based on power and power is based on RSSI so why bother converting RSSI to any other meaningful quantity and then averaging that number - that uses too much CPU power.

Answer (score 0):

I want to expand on my comment a bit though it has overlap with what Andy and Olin have said.

Using RSSI for localization (finding distances) can be somewhat unpredictable even in laboratory settings where noise has been minimized.  On the positive side, there are some instances where it does behave well enough.  The first thing you should do is take some measurements and see if it acts even close to predictably in your setting.  I can offer more information on different methods here but first you should just take samples in several configurations that will be likely to occur with your device and see if the relative RSSI measurement reflects the relative distances.

Once you have done that, if it all seems predictable enough then what you want to do quantify this predictability by computing the probability distributions. This allows you to change the inference from statements such as "By the RSSI reading, I am sure that the distance is 5m" to "By the RSSI reading indicating a distance of 5m, I am 90% sure that that the object is between 4m and 6m".** There are various methods that can be used here, let me know if you are interested.

When Olin says that "log" is not suitable for averaging, what this means to me is assuming the distance measurement has error function that is equally likely to be +e as -e then "log" will have a skewed error. On the other hand, without experiments and predetermining the distribution of the error you don't really know which measurement is skewed and which is not.  They may even both be skewed depending on your application.

Once you've determined the distribution you end up with the problem that Andy mentioned.  How computable is this? In other words, you need to take the probability distribution of the RSSI signal or distance and then compute the probability distribution of the smoothed signal.  This will vary greatly depending on the probability distribution of the error and will likely determine where it makes most sense to put your filter.  I think in either situation you are likely going to need a filter with very low \$\alpha\$

** You can do this process whether or not your data is predictable.  The problem is you could be interested in determining when the object has moved 1m and get results such as "I am 90% sure the object has moved between -1m and 4m" or reversing this question "How sure am I that the object has moved 1m? 15%."

Comment: Is the difficulty with using RSSI a result of it being an instantaneous rather than time-averaged measurement within most devices that report it?  If so, how much extra circuitry would be required to make the measurement of RSSI be something of a time-averaged result?

Comment: Even with time averaged samples the prediction in very controlled settings can still be sporadic.

Comment: Even with continuous averaging, or do you mean averaged repeatedly at some sampling rate which is low relative to the RF frequency?

Comment: Both.  If you google RSSI and distance you should encounter scientific studies with various set-ups.